# Cannot get a many to many relationship to properly work using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got 3 tables; user, location and location_favorite.
location_favorite being kind of like a association table. I'm trying to be able to create a list of favorite locations forf the user using that table.

user class looks like this:

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Date, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from model import Base
from model.address import Address
from model.group import Group
from model.location_favorite import LocationFavorite


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    reset_token = Column(String, default=None)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    account_status = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    user_group = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user_groups.id"), \
    nullable=False, default=1)
    registration_date = Column(Date, nullable=False, 
    default=datetime.datetime.now())
    last_online = Column(Date, default=datetime.datetime.now())


    # Relationships
    address = relationship(Address, uselist=False, back_populates="user")
    group = relationship(Group, back_populates='users')
    spots = relationship("Location")
    favorite_spots = relationship('Location', secondary='location_favorite', 
    backref='favorited_by')
```

location class looks like this:

```
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, unique=True)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
    creator_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longtitude = Column(Float)
    creation_date = Column(Date, default=datetime.now)

    # Relationships
    creator = relationship('User', foreign_keys=creator_id, 
    back_populates='spots')
    events = relationship('Event')
    favorited_by = relationship('User', secondary='location_favorite', 
    backref='favorite_spots')
```

and the location_favorite class looks like this:

```
class LocationFavorite(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'location_favorite'
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('location.id'), 
    primary_key=True)
    creation_date = Column(Date, default=datetime.now)
```

Now that gives me the following exception:

```
Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on 
relationship User.favorite_spots
```

I suppose that is a logical response because the user doesn't have any reference to location_favorite except for the user_id.. which is a part of a composite primary key. I just can't figure out what would be the best way to create this relationship.

Comment: Not sure if this is the root of the problem but you are using the `backref` keyword parameter for `User.favorite_spots` and `Location.favorited_by` even though you are defining the relationship on both sides. Should use `back_populates`. I don’t know that that fixes your original issue but just something that stands out to me.

Comment: Mmh that doesn't seem to fix the issue, I thought back_populates did the same as backref.

Comment: `backref` is a shortcut for placing the relationship on both sides. Define relationship on one one side with `backref`, and it will be available on other side with the attribute name being whatever you passed to backref parameter. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html. Sorry it didn’t solve your issue but just stood out to me when I read your question and I wasn’t around a computer to test.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for explaining.

Comment: So the actual issue is that you define your FK on `LocationFavorite.user_id` as `ForeignKey('user.id')`, but `User.__tablename__ = 'users'`, so FK should be `ForeignKey('users.id')`. Fix that and then you'll see the problem with using `backref` after defining the relationship on both sides.

Comment: Awesome! That indeed fixed my issue, thanks!